# Can't access number of items on navigational property

Tags: ef-code-first, automapper, entity-framework-core

I'm not sure if this issue is an Automapper-issue or a Entity Framework-issue.

I'm having trouble getting the number of products from the navigation property `ProductCount` in my viewmodel. The value returned is always `"0"`. If the function worked, it would return `"no"` on a category with no products and `"15"` on a category with 15 products.

The viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public ViewModelProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProductCategory> Children { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }

    public string ProductCount
    {
        get
        {
            return Products != null
                ? Products.Count().ToString()
                : "no";
        }
    }
}
```

To display number of products:

```
@model List<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelProductCategory>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{   
    @item.Title has @item.ProductCount product(s).
}
```

I have also tried to use `@item.Products.Count()` in the view, but that always returns `0`.

This is how the viewmodel gets populated:

```
// Getting the categories
List<ProductCategory> DbCategories = _context.ProductCategories
                        .Include(e => e.Children).ToList().OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)
                        .Where(e => e.ParentId == null).ToList();
// Mapping to ViewModel
List<ViewModelProductCategory> MapCategory = 
    _mapper.Map<List<ProductCategory>, List<ViewModelProductCategory>>(DbCategories);
```

The mapping:

```
CreateMap<ProductCategory, ViewModelProductCategory>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Products, opt => opt.MapFrom(
                src => src.ProductInCategory.Select(pc => pc.Product)));
```

`ProductInCategory` is a linking table between categories and products:

```
public class ProductInCategory
// A linking table for which products belongs to which categories
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    // Nav.props.:
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Why can't I get the number of products?

**Edit**

With the help of @IvanStoev in the comments, I changed the query to this:

```
//get all categories, so we have each and every child in Context
        List<ProductCategory> DbCategories = _context.ProductCategories
                        .Include(e => e.Children)
                        .Include(e => e.ProductInCategory)
                            .ThenInclude(p => p.Product)
                        .ToList().OrderBy(o => o.SortOrder)
                        .Where(e => e.ParentId == null).ToList();
```

Now it works! Yay!

Comment: EF currently (with no lazy loading support) will not give you data you haven't requested. If you need products, then request products - `.Include(e => e.Products)`

Comment: Not in the mapping, in the EF source - `DbCategories = ...`. Before/after `.Include(e => e.Children)`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. :)